# Why c++ use throw() keyword to indicate the function won't throw any exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, exception-specification

Is this keyword a bit of counter-intuitive ?

The function won't throw any exceptions so we add a throw() tag to it. Should it be silent() or something like that?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec

Comment: It is what it is, or rather was, and the only answer to 'why?' is 'because Bjarne Stroustrup'.

Answer (score 4):

From a pre-C++17 perspective: it may be counter-intuitive, but only for a moment. `throw(type, type, ...)` provides a list of types of exceptions that the function may throw. `throw()` is supplying an *empty* list of types, i.e. the function cannot throw any type of exception.

Answer (score 1):

`throw()` = can throw exactly those exceptions:""

That is, can't throw anything.

Historically, a real list was provided: `throw(X,Y,Z)` meant "can throw `X`, or `Y` or `Z`". That syntax was removed because it wasn't really useful: the most useful guarantee is that a function can't throw anything.

Answer (score 1):

A function can optionally be declared with a `throw()` specifier, known as an [exception specification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec), to list the type of exceptions it is allowed to throw. If the list is empty, the function is not allowed to throw any exception at all.  If the function has a `throw()` specifier and throws an exception that is not in the list, the program is terminated immediately by default (this behavior can be customized at runtime).

This uses of a `throw()` specifier was deprecated in C++11, and the specific case of an empty `throw()` specifier was replaced with the new [`noexcept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) specifier.

The non-empty `throw()` specifier was removed from the language in C++17, and the empty `throw()` specifier was removed in C++20.

Answer (score -3):

The keyword is deprecated, in current standard it's 'noexcept'

Comment: No, `throw` is used to throw exceptions.

Comment: Clarification: the **keyword** is used in multiple places, including _throw expressions_ and _exception specifications_. See Remy Labeau's answer on the latter. The keyword isn't deprecated and in fact is in active use for throw statements.

Comment: The keyword is deprecated for exception specification